# How much current can opamps' integrated ESD diodes carry during an ESD strike?

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, esd, diode-clamp

So the basic answer to such kinds of questions is usually: *"If nothing is specified in the datasheet, assume the most conservative rating!"*

However, the datasheets usually only mention the DC limit in the absolute max ratings (usually a few mA for the input diodes).

Documents such as [this from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvaex7/slvaex7.pdf) clearly state, however:

> Because this protection structure is designed for high-energy, short-duration ESD events, the diodes must be
> protected from destruction during the longer instances of Electrical Overstress (EOS). During EOS events, the
> applied voltage may be a lot lower. For example, it may be in the region of 500mV over the supply voltage rather
> than 1kV. However, these scenarios also last for much longer periods of time. The level of current that the
> protection diodes can sustain under EOS is often given in the "Absolute Maximum" section of the data sheet as
> ±10mA. Nonetheless, it is advisable to keep this number under ±1mA when possible.

So it tells that the absolute maximum rating applies to longer EOS, and also mentions tentatively that ESD overstress can be a 1000 times higher.

### Question:

Does that mean that for some 10s of nanosecond long ESD and EFT events, these current steering structures are designed to tolerate much higher currents (Amps) ?

Because when I try to design the protection circuitry such, that the current will be below 10 mA even during the ESD event, I either end up with Schottky rail clamps or considerable series resistors of at least 1 kOhm, both of which are not tolerable in my application due to leakage and noise requirements.

[OPA145](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa145.pdf) datasheet for reference.

Comment: The data sheet limit for current applies in the nano second rage as well as for continuous over-current because, when the current is exceeded (even for a few nano seconds) there is a parasitic BJT (not always but usually) that turns into a thyristor and shorts the IC internal rails. Thus is burns. Well, that's how it used to be back in the 70s, 80s, 90s etc..

Comment: @Andyaka What is your guess at section "6.2 ESD Ratings" in the OPA145 datasheet? It has a HBM rating. Without any additional information I would interpret that this applies under all conditions (including a powered-up state). Or does the additional note about JEDEC safe device manufacturing guideline suggest that the ESD rating only applies for manufacturing (where the chip isn't powered obviously)

Comment: What are you trying to protect? where leakage and noise requirements are too stringent? Yet is also disconnectable requiring ESD protection?

Comment: The HBM model uses a 1k5 resistor as far as I remember so, 500 volts/1500 = 333 mA.

Comment: I meant the purpose of the input.

Comment: @DKNguyen It is not strictly an input. It is multifunctional. Under different operation scenarios it can be either a high impedance node (thus the low leakage requirement) or low impedance node (hence the low noise requirement).

Comment: I'd question whether these leakage and noise requirements are unnecessarily high then.

Comment: @DKNguyen Fine. That explains at least why it seems so hard to comply with the 10 mA under all conditions. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that for some 10s of nanosecond long ESD and EFT
> events, these current steering structures are designed to tolerate
> much higher currents (Amps) ?

What it comes down to is dissipated energy and the temperature of the part. A short pulse does not dissipate a lot of energy. If you look at a resistor (even for a diode a lot of the heating comes from ohmic heating)

$$ P = \frac{\Delta q}{\Delta t}V = IV$$

the power dissipation is related to the amount of time the charge is being dissipated and the quantity.

So, if you have a short pulse in the 10ns range, you can have a large quantity of charge. But if you have a long time (from seconds to minutes, the amount of power increases substantially, even for a lower voltage.

In many cases, part death happens through a material change when the temperature gets too high inside of the part. The epoxy melts first usually and then as the temperature goes higher, metals and semiconductors start to melt.

A good thing to try is to simulate pulses in spice on your protection circuit and look at the power dissipation in each circuit element.

Comment: Yeah power dissipation is pretty low (or rather total dissipated energy is rather low). But isn't latch-up also a concern ? Or does that not occur for such short events ?

Comment: Latch up does not happen in diodes, unless they are part of an IC

Comment: I haven't removed the package of an opamp yet, but I was pretty sure that the ESD diodes are on the same die, as the rest of the amplifier