On PCB Hourglass shaped ESD protection - any info on how to use it
I've seen the hourglass like copper structure on a PCB board and the silk suggests it's ESD protection.
It's sitting close to the USB port.

I've never seen this.
Does anyone have information about:

How to use it?
If it's protected (patent)?
How it works (but the how to use it would anwser that).

@dave-tweed Points out another question  Pattern on a PCB .  It is at least similar, but IMHO the question is different as it asked to identify the structure.
This questions focuses on how to use it and if it's protected by a patent or so.
The NXP document referenced in one of the responses does not mention spark gaps like these.
However, I did not know the term, so I can look for "Spark Gaps" now.
It's not used on a mains in this project, the board only has a USB-C port to power it and an ethernet port which has the usual means of protection.

You may find this discussion of interest: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/606794/how-much-current-can-opamps-integrated-esd-diodes-carry-during-an-esd-strike/721337#721337 Not to give away too much in a comment, but the structure is likely an air spark gap.

BTW, the different geometry, i.e., triangle points, is likely to lower the break-over voltage by increasing the voltage gradient at a sharp point. See https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/58047

Thanks TimWilliams and DrMoishePippik .  Making the structure pointy  focuses the charge in the point so that helps with that, but points are also more easily etched away but that isn't an issue today.  Thanks to the name of this structure I found some interesting videos on spark gaps so I got most of my answers there.

There is a patent for this structure: US20080266730A1 but has been abandoned so it's legally safe to use ;-).
